# Listview not refreshed after removing element

Tags: nativescript

Hello guys Im new to nativescript and Im having problem, with listview not refreshing or removing item, when item is deleted.
Here is my sample code...

ViewModel.js

```
const observableModule = require('data/observable');

const Item = (function (_super) {
    __extends(Item, _super);
    function Item(props) {
        const _this = _super.call(this) || this;
        _this.id = props.id;
        _this.ind = props.ind;
        _this.status = props.status;
        return _this;
    }
    return Item;
}(observableModule.Observable));


function Items(Data) {

    let viewModel = {};
    viewModel = new observableModule.fromObjectRecursive({
        items: Data || [],
    });

       viewModel.getItems = function () {
        return server.serverService()
            .then((data) => {
                const list = data.data;
                const formattedList = setListForDisplay(list);
                viewModel.tickets = formattedList;
                return formattedList;
            });
    };

}

function setListForDisplay(list) {
    if (!list.length) { return []; }
    const formattedList = [];
    list.forEach((ticket, ind) => {
        const created = dateService(ticket.created);
        item.date = new Date();
        item.index = ind;
        formattedList[ind] = new Item(item);
    });
    return formattedList;
}
module.exports = Items;
```

View Module

```
  <lv:RadListView id="dataList" items="{{ items }}" >
                <lv:RadListView.itemTemplate>
                        <GridLayout class="ab_tp_item" tap="itemDelete" rows="*" columns="*" >
<Label row="0" col="auto"  text="random text" />
                        </GridLayout>
                </lv:RadListView.itemTemplate>
            </lv:RadListView>
```

items.js

```
const timer = require('timer');
let ItemsModel = require('../view-models/items-view-model');

ItemsModel = new ItemsModel();
function DataLoaded(args) {
  const page = args.object;
   page.bindingContext = ItemsModel;
  timer.setTimeout(() => {
        ItemsModel.getItems()
            .then((list) => {
            });
    }, 100);
}

function itemDelete() {
  page.bindingContext.items.splice(1,1);
}
module.exports = {
   DataLoaded,
   itemDelete
};
```

Problem is when I try to delete item with itemDelete function it doesnt do anything it seems like it removed element from the list, but view doesnt get updated at all... Wha could be the problem Im assuming Im creating Items the wrong way in view model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... There's a lot wrong here. First in order to handling binding you have to use an Observable Array().

That should fix what you have going on but even then you have problems because you don't have a method if knowing which item you tapped. Your itemDelete assumes you're automatically deleting the 2nd item in your list. That's not going to be very useful.

I see you're copying come come from a typescript compiler and adding it with your code. I attempted to fix your code but decided that I'd just do a playground app to show you a working example.

Go to the playground here https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=Z5745I&v=3

Go to the home-view-model.js.

See the getItems function. I give you two ways of adding items to your observable array

You can either push the items or just overwrite the property with another observable Array.

Also, if you want to pass an array to your object, then it still needs to be an observable array or the page won't refresh.

Next thing is I'm not sure why you set timeout on your page load either. You want to get that started as soon as possible since you have to go else to get your data. Plus, you're running this after the page is available cause your binding your view model to the page so again there's no reason to use a timeout. Let me know if this helps. Good luck. I know how it feels to just be getting started with Nativescript. The documentation isn't as straight forward as they'd hope and they've now removed all the good tutorials from the docs website. Wish you had access to the old groceries tutorial. It was a great way to get started with clear concise instructions.

Plus since people here hate link (they can be broken relatively easy, here's the code in the 3 files

View XML

```
<Page 
loaded="pageLoaded" 
class="page" 
xmlns:lv="nativescript-ui-listview"
xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd">

<ActionBar title="Home" class="action-bar">
</ActionBar>
<StackLayout>
    <lv:RadListView items="{{ items }}">
        <lv:RadListView.itemTemplate>
            <StackLayout orientation="horizontal">
                <Label fontSize="20" text="{{ userId }}" />
                <Label fontSize="14" text="{{ title }}" />
                <Button text="Delete" tap="delete"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </lv:RadListView.itemTemplate>
    </lv:RadListView>
</StackLayout>
```

View JS

```
var frameModule = require("ui/frame");
var ItemsModel = require("./home-view-model");

var itemsModel = new ItemsModel();

exports.pageLoaded = function(args) {
    var page = args.object;
    page.bindingContext = itemsModel;
    itemsModel.getItems();
}

exports.delete = function (args) {
    var item = args.object.bindingContext;
    let id = item.id;
    itemsModel.remove(id);
}
```

View Model JS

```
var observableModule = require("data/observable");
var ObservableArray = require("data/observable-array").ObservableArray;
var http = require("http");


function HomeViewModel(Data) {
    var viewModel = observableModule.fromObject({
    items: Data || new ObservableArray(),
 });

viewModel.emptyList = function () {
    while (this.items.length) {
        this.items.pop();
    }
}

viewModel.remove = function (node) {
    let index = this.items.map(function (e) { return e.id;}).indexOf(node);
    this.items.splice(index, 1); 
} 

viewModel.getItems = function () {
    var vm = this;
    /* 
    * Way One If you don't need to normalize the data
    */

    /* 
        return http.getJSON("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
          .then((response) => {
              vm.items = new ObservableArray(response);
          }, (e) => {
              console.log(e.message);
          }); 
    */

   /* 
    * Way TWo If you need to normalize the data
    */
     return http.getJSON("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
      .then((response) => {
          let length = response.length;
          for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
              let el = response[i];
              el.title = 'Something different ' + i;
              vm.items.push(el);
          }
      }, (e) => {
          console.log(e.message);
      }); 
    };
    return viewModel;
}

module.exports = HomeViewModel;
```